# Compare whether values in dataframe are greater than values in a series by column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have the following dataframe and series

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([1,2,2], pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=3, freq='D'))
test = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([1, 2], index=['a', 'b'])] * len(ser), index=ser.index)
```

Let's say I want to compare whether each value in the dataframe is larger than the corresponding values in the series, by column.  I know that I can do it in the following way:

`test.apply(lambda x: x > ser)`

However, is there also a way to do this using np.where that is perhaps more efficient?  I know that if I were comparing the dataframe to the series by rows, the following would work:

```
np.where(test > [0.5,2], 1, 0)
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work to create a valid data frame as ser is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with `axis=0`:

```
test.gt(ser, axis=0)

#                a      b
#2020-01-01  False   True
#2020-01-02  False  False
#2020-01-03  False  False
```

---

Quick benchmark against `apply`:

```
import time

def apply_compare():
    t1 = time.time()
    test.apply(lambda x: x > ser)
    print(time.time() - t1)

def gt_compare():
    t1 = time.time()
    test.gt(ser, 0)
    print(time.time() - t1)

ser = pd.Series([1,2,2] * 10000, pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=30000, freq='D'))

test = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([1, 2], index=['a', 'b'])] * len(ser), index=ser.index)

apply_compare()
# 0.006000041961669922

gt_compare()
# 0.0009999275207519531
```